# How can I make my app display a notification in the window shade using MIT App Inventor 2?

Tags: android, app-inventor

I'm making an app that will show a notification in the Android window shade daily, but I can't find anyway to get my app to display a notification.

I know its possible because I've seen apps made in App Inventor that display notifications.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please first [do the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and learn [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Thank you.

Comment: Push messaging is only available in the [Punya framework](http://air.csail.mit.edu/punya/tutorials/#push), see also [here](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/mitappinventortest/WkBSg01e4Q8/srRFiwBzhY4J)